# Filtering a list depending on the key values of another list

Tags: groovy

I have two lists

```
list1 = [ [ key1:'value1', key2:'value2', key3:'value3' ],
          [ key1:'value4', key2:'value5', key3:'value6' ] ]
list2 = [ [ key1:'value10', key2:'value2', key3:'value11' ],
          [ key1:'value7',  key2:'value8', key3:'value9'  ] ]
```

I would like to **remove the entry from list1 when list1 key2 = list2 key2 i.e value2 here**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
List filteredList1 = list1.findAll { !list2.key2.contains( it.key2 ) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, but it doesnt work for me, and not throwing error as well

Comment: Have you tried with the exact code in the question and the exact answer?  Probably an issue with something you're not telling us in your input data ;-)

Comment: Or of course, all of the key2 values in `list1` exist in the key2 values of `list2`...  Is order important?  Does it have to compare the first element of list2 with the first element of list1?  The code in the answer compares each value of list1 with **all** values of list2

Comment: looks like the stringValue() method has to be appended against the key2...hmmmm, i will have a look

Comment: Yeah, do you mean all `list2.key2` values, or just the one at the same index as the element you're checking in `list1`?

Comment: All list2.key2 values against list1.key2

Comment: Right, so the above should work...  I guess you've got some funky values (instead of Strings) that do not implement `hashCode` or `equals`